# c++11: void in template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, void

I was implementing some stuff in C++, and I came across a situation, I did not know how to handle properly. Consider following example

```
template<typename F>
struct function_wrapper;

template<typename Return, typename... Input>
struct function_wrapper<Return(Input...)>
{
    function_wrapper(/*...*/) = /* ... */
    std::tuple<Input...> input_args;
    Return return_value;

    void first_calculate_result() { return_value = somehow_manipulate(input_args); }
    Return operator()() { return return_value; }
}
```

Now, obvious usage is like this

```
my_function<int(double)> stored_fnc(5.5);
stored_fnc.first_calculate_result();
/* something maybe else */
std::cout << "Result is: " << stored_fnc() << std::endl;
```

Everything works as expected, as long as `function`'s return type is not `void`.

My question is, do I have to write partial specification for `my_function<void(Input...)>`, where I would omit all `Return` stuff, or is there an easier way? Moreover, why does the C++ standard does not allow me to define `void` variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do I have to write partial specification for `my_function<void(Input...)>`...

As written, yes. You are saving the return value from your call in a variable, so there's no way around that. However, you could simply *not* write your function_wrapper that way, and have `operator()` simply return:

```
Return operator()() { return somehow_manipulate(input_args); }
```

You're allowed to write code like that even if `Return` is `void` and `somehow_manipulate` is a `void` function. That's how `std::function<R(Args...)>` is implemented. There's no special case for `void`.

> why C++ standard does not allow to define `void` variables?

Because `void` is not a value. A `void` function doesn't return *something* of type `void`, it doesn't return *anything*. It's uniquely nothing. It is emptiness. It is the Buddhist ideal. You cannot have something of nothing.

Comment: Um, `std::function<R(Args...)>` actually *does* have a special case for `void`. It's not expressed as a partial specialization in the standard, but it's there.

Comment: @T.C. Not sure what you mean. What's there?

Comment: Special handling for the `R == void` case. It needs to discard the return value of the wrapped function.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, but there's still no specialization for `std::function<void(Args...)>`. That's what I meant by no special case. It handles it internally. And OP can't if there's a need to hold onto the `Return`.

Comment: You can use `async` or `packaged_task` and let the specialization of `future` handle it :) But it's less efficient than just writing your own specialization, to be sure.